# How to login on Goibibo website using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate `Goibibo` Website in `Selenium` using `Java`. After Clicking on `Sign` in Tab, login pop up is displaying. How to switch to pop up so that I can enter details into the `Goibibo` Pop up. I wrote the following code:

```
public class Testclass1 {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver Driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Driver.manage().window().maximize();        
        Driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    //HANDLE THE POP UP     
          String handle = Driver.getWindowHandle();
          System.out.println(handle);
            // Click on the Button "New Message Window"
            Driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign In")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            // Store and Print the name of all the windows open               
            Set handles = Driver.getWindowHandles();
            System.out.println(handles);
            // Pass a window handle to the other window
            for (String handle1 : Driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                System.out.println(handle1);
                Driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
                }
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            Driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("bittu.agrawal773@gmail.com");
        //WAIT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opened `popup` is not a new window `popup`, it's just simple HTML login popup present is `iframe` which can be simply handled by switching to `iframe` as below working code :-

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Sign In"))).click();

//switch to popup iframe to enter login credentials into form
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("authiframe"));

//now enter login credentials   
driver.findElement(By.id("id_username")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.id("id_password")).sendKeys("password");

//now click on sign in button
driver.findElement(By.id("signinBtn")).click();
```

**Note**:- For better way, you should use [`WebDriverWait`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) to wait explicitly for element with certain [`ExpectedConditions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) instead of `Thread.sleep()`.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. It is working for me. Can you please tell me on what basis you entered "authiframe" while switching to pop up

Comment: Actually this popup login form elements is present inside an iframe which can find after switching to that iframe that's why it's necessary to switch iframe before finding elements. Thanks